# Unable to find a template

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm trying to run an API on symfony 3.0.5. I'm trying to follow [this guide](http://welcometothebundle.com/symfony2-rest-api-the-best-2013-way/) and make some changes according to newer version of sympfony. But i received some strange error.

```
Unable to find template "AppDemoBundle:Page:getPage.html.twig" (looked into: /var/www/html/DemoRESTAPI/app/Resources/views, /var/www/html/DemoRESTAPI/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form)
```

I cannot figure out why symfony doesn't translate the view into correct path and name. If I put a file named `AppDemoBundle:Page:getPage.html.twig` in `/var/www/html/DemoRESTAPI/app/Resources/views`

then code starts working, but this is not what I expected. Controller and setting looks like in his example from https://github.com/liuggio/symfony2-rest-api-the-best-2013-way

Comment: Where exactly did you store the template? Did you create a bundle named `AppDemoBundle`?

Comment: Where template is? Should be in `src/AppDemo/Resources/views/Page/getPage.html.twig`.

Comment: @xabbuh I created a AppDemoBundle

Comment: @malcolm I put it there it isn't working but when i put view with name "AppDemoBundle:Page:getPage.html.twig" into /var/www/html/DemoRESTAPI/app/Resources/views/AppDemoBundle:Page:getPage.html.twig then page starts working.

Comment: Can you show your `AppKernel` class please?

Comment: @xabbuh http://pastebin.com/yy3p2CdK Thank you.

Comment: Are you able to publish your project on GitHub so that we can take a look at it? So far this looks good.

Comment: One more thing: Did you clear the cache after creating the templates?

Comment: @xabbuh Yes i cleared the cache. I will put project on github tomorrow, thank you for help I just try this with version 2.8.0 and everything works fine, with 3.0.5 i had this strange problem.